# add more key values in the elements of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have an array which has the first element like

```
Array ( [name] => gaurav pandey [education] => MCA )
```

Now I want to insert some more properties so the end result should be like:

```
Array ( [name] => gaurav pandey [education] => MCA [occupation] => developer [passion] => programming)
```

How can I achieve that in php? I have seen the dynamic creation of instances and their properties but still can't figure out how to achieve it in php array.

Comment: Please learn to solve such basic problems yourself. Google [php arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and read virtually *any* of the results instead of asking something so fundamental.

Comment: @meagar be assured that some one who has a rep around 958 knows the basic rules of stackoverflow.. it's just that I have come from a .net backbackground, so many a times it becomes hard to search such things.. I did my search already and then asked this here. The problem with the developers like me is that I put the key words in google that can instantly give me the .net specific results.. but in php many a times I can't get the same results. You know I am just beginning and loving php.

Comment: Really? You know how to get .Net results but not PHP results? Did you try including "PHP" in your search terms? Had you Googled "PHP arrays", the first result is the answer. I'm sorry, but questions this simplistic and easily answered are the reason we have "shows no research effort" as a down-vote reason.

Comment: Nope, don't take it other wise.. I just said I tried and could not fine this particular thing that's it. I mean in .net I can normally get 90% of the things from google but in php, I have to take help from peers and SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're just asking how to insert a new key/value into an array, which is an *incredibly* basic PHP syntax question.

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), specificall [Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying):

> To change a certain value, assign a new value to that element using its key. To remove a key/value pair, call the unset() function on it.
>
> ```
>  <?php
>  $arr = array(5 => 1, 12 => 2);
>
>  $arr[] = 56;    // This is the same as $arr[13] = 56;
>                 // at this point of the script
>
>  $arr["x"] = 42; // This adds a new element to
>                 // the array with key "x"
>
>  unset($arr[5]); // This removes the element from the array
>
>  unset($arr);    // This deletes the whole array
>  ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for adding properties to an array:

```
$a = array (
    "name" => "gaurav pandey",
    "education" => "MCA"
);
$a["occupation"] = "developer";
$a["passion"] = "programming"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the [PHP Manual about Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) first. And check this example:

```
// create the associative array:
$array = array(
    'name' => 'gaurav pandey'
);

// add elements to it
$array ['education'] = 'MCA';
$array ['occupation'] = 'Developer';
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @meagar's post, id also suggest taking a look at the array_functions pages in the php manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

eg, combining arrays, traversing arrays, sorting arrays, etc.

you can also merge arrays

```
<?php
$array1 = array("name" => "gaurav pandey","education" => "MCA");
$array2 = array("color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", "occupation" => "developer", "passion" => "programming");
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array_push()` too. This is handy if you're adding more than one item at once to the array but has a little overhead attached.